# Multiple Conditions in MailMerge Field

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

I would like to include up to 3 conditions in a `MailMerge` field. Below is my current field which returns `1` if `checkbox1` is `checked`.

```
if"<<cb1>>"="Yes" "Checked""Unchecked"
```

I would like to include checking of additional `cb2` and `cb3`, to check if any of them are checked.

May I know how can it be done?

p.s. I left out the `{ }` colons which I am not sure if it will be required here.

---

Edit: Tried the following structure but the output was `Yes`

```
if
    "if"<<cb1>>"="Yes" "1""0""
    + 
    "if"<<cb2>>"="Yes" "1""0""
    +
    "if"<<cb3>>"="Yes" "1""0""
>0 
    "1 or more checked""None checked"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a field coded as:

{IF{={IF«cb1»= "Yes" 1 0}+{IF«cb2»= "Yes" 1 0}+{IF«cb3»= "Yes" 1 0}}> 0 "1 or more checked" "None checked"}

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above example are all created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac or, if you’re using a laptop, you might need to use Ctrl-Fn-F9); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. Nor is it practical to add them via any of the standard Word dialogues. Likewise, the chevrons (i.e. '« »') are part of the actual mergefields - which you can insert from the 'Insert Merge Field' dropdown (i.e. you can't type or copy & paste them from this message, either). The spaces represented in the field constructions are all required.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can create a field with logic such as: “If Condition 1 is met, then if Condition 2 is also met, display Result 1”. This is equivalent to saying “if both conditions are met, display Result 1”; but unfortunately you can't use “and” in Word fields.

Such a field would look something this:

```
{ IF [Condition 1] { IF [Condition 2] [Display Result 1] "" } "" }
```

The easiest way to create nested fields of this type is to create them separately, then cut and paste one field into the other.

[Source](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MailMerge/MMergeIfFields.htm)